# Is there any performance difference between catching Exception or certain type exception ? - Java

Tags: java, try-catch

I wonder whether can be a difference or performance issues between those 2 blocks:

```
    try{
        return Integer.parseInt(numAsString);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return onErrorInt;
    }
```

and

```
    try{
        return Integer.parseInt(numAsString);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return onErrorInt;
    }
```

Sometimes there is even inside the try many kind of exceptions like:

```
    try{
        // open file then try to close
        // try to parse integer
        // another kind of exception throwing funcitons
    }catch (Exception e){
        return onErrorInt;
    }
```

and

```
    try{
        // open file then try to close
        // try to parse integer
        // another kind of exception throwing funcitons
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return // something;
    } catch (IOException e){
        // return same thing in the exception above
    }
```

.

What i am doing is System that will stay running 24 hours a day with 1 restart per day.

In many places i dont care about the type of the Exception, i just need to let my app running all the time. So mainly my question about **performance**.

Comment: When you catch a specific one you can handle it specifically?

Comment: Until you proove this piece of code is causing performance issues you should do the _right_ thing. The question as it stands doesn't make sense. The difference if any will not be anything you will notice.

Comment: If you're worrying about performance of catching exception you're probably throwing them too often and there's something terribly wrong with your code.

Comment: My system will stay up all day on android, sometime i get exception like connection issues or wrong packet or something ignorable. So i do care of keeping the system up all day. @SergeyTachenov

Comment: IMO the performance impact to catch them specifically is incredible low (Comparable to an if). However a very noticeable amount of time/performance is needed to throw the Exceptions (generate stacktrace etc). If you need max performance, then don't throw exceptions at all.

Comment: _Sometimes_ maybe. But that won't cause any *performance* issues. Of course you'll have to catch exceptions to keep the system up and running, but performance shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do your future self & other maintainers a favor by catching each exception  separately and logging it properly at the least...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Performance difference? Practically nothing.** The only cost is iterating through the ExceptionTable, which is a very low profile, in-memory operation. you can read a a short summary about the internals here:

[JVM spec on Exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10)

The main reason for distinguishing between exception types is to allow developers to take different actions upon different type of exceptions if it is needed.